# Net-SNMP support for TCP and UDP MIBs

Tags: net-snmp

Does Net-SNMP support the TCP and UDP MIBs out-of-the-box?

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/tcp.html

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/udp.html

Does Net-SNMP have a built-in agent that exposes the TCP and UDP MIB information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NET-SNMP framework provides SNMP agent with quite broad RFC support. If you want to enable MIB module handlers for TCP-MIB and UDP-MIB just enable them while executing configuration script using following option:

```
./configure --with-mib-modules=udp-mib,tcp-mib
```

However, you may check if these MIBs are enabled by default (this may depend on NET-SNMP version used) by performing simple snmpwalk command on 1.3.6.1.2.1.6 OID.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Recompiling your SNMP agent is not the best way way to enable MIBs that ship with the agent itself. :P

Answer (score 1):

The TCP-MIB *is* shipped with net-snmp, but the agent doesn't publish it by default.  Edit your /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf and add this line in the same stanza as the similar lines:

```
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.6
```

You may have to change 'systemview' to 'system', or whatever name is used in your particular distro.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you can retrieve any published SNMP information via Net-SNMP. If the agent publishes it then you're going to be able to get/walk that info.

The only configuration I would perhaps expect is that you need the appropriate MIB installed at the manager/client end, such that you can translate the OIDs to names.

Comment: My question is: does Net_SNMP have a built-in Agent that published the TCP/UDP information?